# concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() not calling method inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am tring to use **concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()** inside a class. but method **operation_data** which is responsible to call method **operation** is not calling it. *"inside concurrent insert" and "do some operations"* is not getting printed.

```
import concurrent.futures

class ConcurrentTest:

    def operation(self, chunk):
        print("inside concurrent insert")
        print("do some operations")

    def operation_data(self):
        chuck_list = [chunk for chunk in self.chunks([millions_of_data_in_this_list], 10000)]
        print('chunk list done')
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for c in chuck_list:
                executor.submit(operation, c)
        print("done")

    @staticmethod
    def chunks(l, n):

        for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
            yield l[i:i + n]


concurrent_test = ConcurrentTest()
concurrent_test.operation_data()
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

change `executor.submit(operation, c)` to

```
executor.submit(self.operation, c)
```

or use [`Executor.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) instead

```
executor.map(self.operation, chunk_list)
```

Note, using `map()` allows you to submit the original list in chunks, allowing you to further simplify your code by passing your big list directly

```
executor.map(self.operation, your_big_list, chunksize=n)
```

EDIT: As noted in the comments by @Booboo you will not get parallelization
by calling future.result() immediately after submit, so I edited my answer accordingly.

EDIT2: Here is full example with executor.map whit all unnecessary code removed and using `chunksize` argument

```
import concurrent.futures

class ConcurrentTest:
    def operation(self, chunk):
        print(f"{chunk} inside concurrent insert")
        print(f"do some operations with {chunk}")

    def operation_data(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(self.operation, range(20), chunksize=3)
        print("done")

concurrent_test = ConcurrentTest()
concurrent_test.operation_data()
```

output (yours may differ):

```
0 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 0
1 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 1

--- skipped for brevity ---

13 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 13
14 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 14
18 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 18
19 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 19
15 inside concurrent insert
11 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 15
16 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 16
do some operations with 11
17 inside concurrent insert
do some operations with 17
done
```

Comment: If you call `submit` and then immediately call `result()` on the returned `Future` instance, you will get no parallelization.

Comment: @Booboo I don't know why do you think so, but even the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) does exactly the same. Also I tested it (with print of numbers from a long list) and clearly they are not printed in order. Please, suggest improvement if you think it is needed.

Comment: Well, for starters, that example had a pool size of 1 and you would never get parallelization with such a pool size anyway, Look at that example again. If you are in a loop where you submit a single task (with `submit`) and then wait for the result (with `future.result()`) before doing your next `submit`, *how can you possibly have more than one task running at a time regardless of your pool size?*

Comment: @Booboo, OK, I see you point. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: What the OP had originally, which was not to wait on the Future at all, was actually better in a sense. The `with` block will terminate with an implicit `shutdown(wait=True)`, which will wait for all outstanding tasks to complete. Of course, you will never detect any exceptions that way. Even if a `with` block was not used, the program will never terminate until all the outstanding tasks completed. The other alternative, of course, is for you to save all the Futures in a list and only then call `result` on each one. But, `map` is a much better alternative with a suitable *chunksize* argument.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer in that part to just refer to `self.operation`. Thank you once again. Actually I my self don't remember a case when I used `submit`, always `map()`.

Comment: i tried using map() but this is not calling executing the method self.operation, if i am doing future.result() this is executing the method. what is the problem with map()?

Comment: @young_minds1, I edited my code to include full example + output